# Is there any Back-end library to generate dynamic images (JPEG/PNG) renderred from an HTML template?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, puppeteer, html-templates

I want to know for my react native app, I want to generate a dynamic image rendered from an HTML template to share when I share something from the app to a Whatsapp contact? What should be the best way to do so? The FE or the BE? I already have puppeteer in place at the backend, but generating images using it seems quite slow, please mention if you have any puppeteer optimizations or any other library or technique? Thanks
**NOTE**: My B.E is in Nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

emm，I do not konw any back-end library to do it.but i had development this feature by FE library.it is quickly?

1. FE(javascript):use library(same as [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) etc.) to reader from an HTML template to image base64,then post base64 data to server
2. BE(nodejs):use Buffer transefer to image,then save,and then response a url

thanks.