# Node.js Generate Dynamic png image without canvas

Tags: node.js, dynamic-image-generation

I need to generate a image without canvas without existing png file.
Thing i want writing some text to png
then sending it using express js. (I not going to save it to disk, send to user on the fly)
(Reason im asking this is i cannot install node-canvas beacuse node-gyp causing issues.)

like

```
res.contentType("image/png"); res.send(pngBytes);
```

Any libraries i can do it, with a example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any Back-end library to generate dynamic images (JPEG/PNG) renderred from an HTML template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62016822/is-there-any-back-end-library-to-generate-dynamic-images-jpeg-png-renderred-fr)